# Reaction mechanism for 7-hydroxy-4-methylcoumarin synthesis with an iodine catalyst

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

7-Hydroxy-4-methylcoumarin can be synthesized from ethyl acetoacetate and resorcinol with iodine as a catalyst. What is the mechanism for this? From what I understand it follows the Pechmann reaction but I'm having trouble to understand how it works in this particular case.

[image: Reaction scheme]

Comment: @bon I'm on it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/314/art%253A10.1007%252Fs10562-007-9186-6.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs10562-007-9186-6&token2=exp=1463164694~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F314%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs10562-007-9186-6.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs10562-007-9186-6*~hmac=4ede03637bd14ef4278db1aff59d8b42f43f4a81e009dae5dd4a573c0160eb4d) about this exact reaction, but in addition to the use of $\ce{I2}$ it mentions the use of microwaves. In the reaction, $\ce{I2}$ acts as a Lewis acid, catalyzing both the transesterificaiton and electrophilic aromatic substitution reactions. It can be seen acting as such in the first step of the mechanism:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image: Step 1]

Next, a proton transfer occurs:

[image: Step 2]

Next, the resorcinol derivative can act as a nucleophile, and ethanol is ejected, completing the transesterification reaction:

[image: step 3]

[image: step 4]

Next, $\ce{I2}$ coordinates to the keto carbonyl, activating the carbon towards electrophilic addition. Because this resorcinol derivative is so activated by the $\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{-OOCR}$ groups, a weak Lewis acid like $\ce{I2}$ is sufficient to catalyze the reaction:

[image: Step 5]

$\hspace{1.5cm}$[image: Step 6]

$\hspace{1.8cm}$[image: Step 7]

$\hspace{1.6cm}$[image: Step 8]